# SwiftUI detect when contextMenu is open

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As the title says, is there any way I can detect (e.g. using a `@State` variable) when either any context menu is open, or the context menu of a specific view is open?

As a basic idea, I would like to print something if it is open. This does not work:

```swift
.contextMenu {
   print("open")
}
```

This also does not seem to work:

```swift
.contextMenu {
    EmptyView()
    .onAppear {
        print("open")
    }
}
```

**How could i make this work?**

---

**Edit:** Why i think its even possible to do it or at least possible to make it look like its possible: On instagram, one can see individual posts as a square only. However using long-press, a context menu opens, and now the post shape is different, but even more there is also a small title above it.. How would one do that? Did they modify the view when the context menu open or is the grid view the post is in before just hiding those details (true image shape + image title) but they are rendered already?

Screenshots:

[image] [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72714335/swiftui-notification-when-contextmenu-is-dismissed-ios/74935849#74935849

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach is to use simultaneous gesture for this purpose, like

```
Text("Demo Menu")
    .contextMenu(menuItems: {
        Button("Button") {}
    })
    .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5).onEnded { _ in
        print("Opened")
    })
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Technically your example seems to be doing what I showed in my example (i.e. printing something), However could I also use this `simultaneousGesture` to change the view that is displayed inside the context menu?

Comment: I was having big issues because SwiftUI does not handle well simultaneous modal views - I had a Sheet with menus and popovers that could not be dismissed. Your solution here helped me to find a workaround. Kinda ugly code when you need such a redundancy, but it finally solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: If this is applied to an element within a `ScrollView` you can no longer scroll on the items.